# Number of generators of an ideal of the polynomial ring over a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

So, there's a passing comment in the very first chapter of Atiyah-Macdonald saying:

> If $K[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ is a polynomial ring, where $K$ is a field, then the ideal consisting of all polynomials with no constant term can not be generated by less than $n$ generators as an ideal.

Is this statement trivial and can it be proven in the framework of basic algebra? Or does it require some advanced machinery like dimension theory?

Comment: No, you don't need dimension theory to prove it. If $I=(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ then $I/I^2$ is a $K$-vector space of dimension ...? What if $I$ is generated by less than $n$ elements?

Comment: @user26857 That works, thanks!